# Having this error "UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt@1.0.1"

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm-install

I have a problem with installing grunt via "npm i". I have tried with 0.4.5 too, but same error. Any idea about what happening ?

For helping, these are my dependencies :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "arrify": "1.0.1",
    "as-jqplot": "1.0.8",
    "babel-runtime": "6.9.2",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "bootstrap-slider": "9.1.1",
    "chart.js": "1.0.2",
    "chunk": "0.0.2",
    "clone": "1.0.2",
    "co": "4.6.0",
    "co-body": "4.2.0",
    "co-pg": "2.0.0",
    "expect": "1.20.2",
    "font-awesome": "4.6.3",
    "github": "2.2.0",
    "grunt": "1.0.1",
    "grunt-babel": "6.0.0",
    "grunt-bump": "0.8.0",
    "grunt-cli": "1.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "1.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "1.0.0",
    "grunt-eslint": "19.0.0",
    "grunt-jsonlint": "1.1.0",
    "grunt-plato": "1.2.1",
    "grunt-shell": "1.3.0",
    "jquery": "3.1.0",
    "koa": "1.2.1",
    "koa-bodyparser": "2.2.0",
    "koa-compress": "1.0.9",
    "koa-cors": "0.0.16",
    "koa-jade": "2.1.0",
    "koa-logger": "1.3.0",
    "koa-router": "5.4.0",
    "koa-sql-select": "1.1.1",
    "koa-static-folder": "0.1.6",
    "koa-useragent": "0.1.4",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "3.5.0",
    "mandrill-api": "1.0.45",
    "md5": "2.1.0",
    "moment": "2.14.1",
    "nconf": "0.8.4",
    "node-noop": "1.0.0",
    "node-persist": "0.0.11",
    "nodemon": "1.9.2",
    "pg": "6.0.3",
    "platform": "1.3.1",
    "plato": "1.6.0",
    "throng": "4.0.0",
    "time-grunt": "1.4.0",
    "typeahead.js": "0.11.1",
    "validator": "5.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-aws": "0.6.2"
  }
```

Even there is the error, grunt is installed. But this error made continuous intgration and deployment on heroku failing.

Comment: It is extremely important that you post the actual error output. Your dependency manifest looks correct (although many of those should really be in `devDependencies`, not `dependencies`), so I would first do a fresh install with `rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install`. If that does not work, try `npm install --loglevel verbose` and show us the output.

Comment: It was on a heroku deployment. I had set up cache clean before each install of my app. And it's heroku, so it's a new container for each deployment. When I tried the same on my own computer, no problem. It was only in production. Without understanding why, this is working now. Complete mistery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NPM 3.10.6 I got no errors when installing all your packages.

```
npm init
rm -rf ./node_modules
(copying your modules to the package.json)
npm i
```

Gave no errors. I suggest you to upgrade your npm

```
npm install -g npm
```

Comment: Woah! Use caution. I just tried this command, then it gave a bunch of errors and recommended running it as root. So I ran `sudo npm install -g npm` and now I'm getting `-bash: /usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory` ...